# What is the significance of single quotes vs double quotes in comparisons?

Tags: c++

This returns an error:

```
return (arg[0] == "-" && arg[1] == "-") ? true : false;
```

*error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer*

However, this does not:

```
return (arg[0] == '-' && arg[1] == '-') ? true : false;
```

What is the difference between `'` and `"` ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Single-quotes denote a character literal.  Double-quotes denote a string literal.

So `'-'` is of type `char`<sup>1</sup>, whereas `"-"` is of type `const char[2]` (which typically decays to `const char *`).

---

<sub>1 `int` in C.</sub>

Comment: `'-'` is of type `char`.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: Interesting, I didn't realised this differed between C++ and C.

Comment: "An ordinary character lineral that contains a signle c-char has type **char**, with the value equal to the numerical value of the encoding of the c-char in the execution character set." (03 C++ standard)

Comment: Indeed. If it were a multicharacter literal (e.g. `'--'`), then it would be of type `int`.